# webmail clients truncates inline styles

Tags: html, css, inline, webmail

some webmail-clients truncates whitespaces in inline-styles. For example this code

```
style="display: inline; float:right; font-size:16px;
```

is rendered as

```
style="display:inline;float:right;font-size:16px;
```

At this point it doesn't hurt. But when I add some background-stylings, my layout crashes:

Origin:

```
background:#ff6600 url('http://localhost:8080/path/to/img.png') no-repeat top right;
```

rendered:

```
background:#ff6600url('http://localhost:8080/path/to/img.png')no-repeattopright;
```

Do you have any ideas how to avoid this behavior? maybe something like "& n b s p;" ?

cheers,
mayo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this

```
<div id="test" style="background:#ff6600; background-image:url('http://www.emofaces.nl/nl/emoticons/z/zwart-en-wit-emoticon.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:bottom left;"></div>
```

See working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/QTLBg/

Comment: as Itay Gal after you wrote i have also used background-position-x and background-position-y.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended before me, you may separate the styling. I offer a small improvement by using `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`

[See the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/QTLBg/1/)